# Terraform unable to get docker to join swarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm trying to use Terraform to spin up some EC2 server which I configure Docker swarm to run on. I got all the code on [this github repo](https://github.com/stabenfeldt/terraform-docker-swarm-aws).

**The error**

```
aws_instance.swarm-node.0 (remote-exec): Connected!
aws_instance.swarm-node.0 (remote-exec): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
aws_instance.swarm-node.0 (remote-exec): flag needs an argument: --token
aws_instance.swarm-node.0 (remote-exec): See 'docker swarm join --help'.
```

**The code that uses --token**

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "echo ===================================",
    "echo JOIN-TOKEN: `docker -H ${aws_instance.swarm-manager.0.private_ip} swarm join-token -q` ",
    "echo ===================================",
    "echo ===================================",
    "sudo docker swarm join ${aws_instance.swarm-manager.0.private_ip}:2377 --token $(docker -H ${aws_instance.swarm-manager.0.private_ip} swarm join-token -q worker)"
  ]
}
```

**The output from the command above:**

```
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): Usage:  docker swarm join-token [-q] [--rotate] (worker|manager)

aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): Manage join tokens
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): JOIN-TOKEN:
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): ===================================
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): ===================================
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): ===================================
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): ===================================
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): ===================================
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
aws_instance.swarm-node.1 (remote-exec): flag needs an argument: --token
```

What should I do to make `$(docker -H ${aws_instance.swarm-manager.0.private_ip}` return a token.

Comment: Does `docker -H ${aws_instance.swarm-manager.0.private_ip} swarm join-token -q worker` return a token?

Comment: The token management should be managed by Terraform or automation configuration tools, such as ansible, puppet, chef, etc after you deployed the infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

First, the 4th line of code is incomplete; You must specify what token you want to print *[worker|manager]*

Please make sure the `docker` daemon is running on both the manager and the worker instances. And that your firewall rules are properly set on both instances as well.